# How to make my links clickable in my html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry but I just have to ask, I have a calorie counter developed to suggest diet regimes for user, I want to make the suggestion appear on after user compute the BMI so that they can clicks on it

[for example, I can click on the suggestion in red sentences in the picture so it will link to my next html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpAHg.png)

Below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Diet Suggestion </title>
 <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
   <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- CUSTOM STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
   
   
   
   <style>
 body {
        background-image: url("background.jpg ");
} 
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



  <tr>
    <td>
  

    <div class="main_view"   style="color:#FFF;text-align:center">
       <a href="#" target="_blank">
       <center> <img src="banner.jpg"  style="width:100%; height:160px;" alt="satisfaction_2015" border="none"  </center> </a>
     
    </div>
        
   
 </td>
   </tr>
    



        </nav>   
           <!-- /. NAV TOP  -->
                <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
    <li class="text-center">
                    <img src="assets/img/find_user.png" class="user-image img-responsive"/>
     </li>
    
     
                    <li>
                        <a  href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
        <li>
                        <a  href="diet_suggest.html"><i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x"></i>Diet Suggestion </a>
                    </li>
     <li>
                        <a  href="today.html"><i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-3x"></i>Today's Menu </a>
                    </li>
                      <li>
                        <a  href="exercise.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>Your Exercise </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="calorie_counter.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>Calorie Counter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="sugar.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>Sugar Counter</a>
                    </li>
     <li>
                        <a  href="food_list.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>Malaysian's Food Calories</a>
                    </li>   
     <li  >
                        <a  href="logoutproc.php"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-3x"></i>Logout</a>
                    </li> 
                        
               
           
                    
              
            </div>
            
        </nav>  
        <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" >
            <div id="page-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-35">
  <body bgcolor="#b5dcb3">
  
  
 <p align="right"><iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" 

style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:240px;height:25px;"src="http://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?

clock=018&timezone=local&color=blue&size=240&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2016,1,1,0,0,0&DateFormat=yyyy / mm / dd DDD&TimeFormat=hh:mm:ss 

TT&Color=blue"></iframe> </p>


<font  face="Lucida Calligraphy" size="6" ><b><h4><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">

<script>

/*
RAINBOW TEXT Script by Matt Hedgecoe (c) 2002
Featured on JavaScript Kit
For this script, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com
*/

// ********** MAKE YOUR CHANGES HERE

var text="Shake it Off" // YOUR TEXT
var speed=50 // SPEED OF FADE

// ********** LEAVE THE NEXT BIT ALONE!


if (document.all||document.getElementById){
document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>')
var storetext=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("highlight") : document.all.highlight
}
else
document.write(text)
var hex=new Array("00","14","28","3C","50","64","78","8C","A0","B4","C8","DC","F0")
var r=1
var g=1
var b=1
var seq=1
function changetext(){
rainbow="#"+hex[r]+hex[g]+hex[b]
storetext.style.color=rainbow
}
function change(){
if (seq==6){
b--
if (b==0)
seq=1
}
if (seq==5){
r++
if (r==12)
seq=6
}
if (seq==4){
g--
if (g==0)
seq=5
}
if (seq==3){
b++
if (b==12)
seq=4
}
if (seq==2){
r--
if (r==0)
seq=3
}
if (seq==1){
g++
if (g==12)
seq=2
}
changetext()
}
function starteffect(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
flash=setInterval("change()",speed)
}
starteffect()

</script>
</b></marquee></font><br>
                  
                            </div>
                </div>
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
                 <hr />
<title>BMI Calculator </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function computeBMI()
    {
        //Obtain user inputs
        var height=Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
        var heightunits=document.getElementById("heightunits").value;
        var weight=Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
        var weightunits=document.getElementById("weightunits").value;


        //Convert all units to metric
        if (heightunits=="inches") height/=39.3700787;
        if (weightunits=="lb") weight/=2.20462;

        //Perform calculation
        var BMI=weight/Math.pow(height,2);

        //Display result of calculation
        document.getElementById("output").innerText=Math.round(BMI*100)/100;

        var output =  Math.round(BMI*100)/100
        if (output<18.5)
        document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight: Suggesting 7 days Weight Gain";
      else   if (output>=18.5 && output<=25)
        document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal: Suggesting Macrobiotic Diet";
     else   if (output>=25 && output<=30)
        document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Obese: Suggesting Low Carbs Diet";
     else   if (output>30)
        document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight: Suggesting Grapefruit Diet";
       // document.getElementById("answer").value = output;    
    }
 </script>
 <body>
<h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter your height: <input type="text" id="height"/>
    <select type="multiple" id="heightunits">
        <option value="metres" selected="selected">metres</option>
        <option value="inches">inches</option>
    </select>
     </p>
<p>Enter your weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/>
    <select type="multiple" id="weightunits">
        <option value="kg" selected="selected">kilograms</option>
        <option value="lb">pounds</option>
    </select>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="computeBMI" onclick="computeBMI();">
<h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>

<h2>This means you are: <span id="comment"> ?</span> </h2>
<br>
<br>
  
 </div>

 </body>
 </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>
     <!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
    <!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
    <!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    

<div id="disclaimer">


<div id="hiaskaki" style="padding:5px 3px;;color:#FFF;text-align:center;font-size:12px;"  >

</div><!--disclaimer-->
 
</div><!--main2-->

</div><!--div4all-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just change

```
<span id="comment"> ?</span>
```

To...

```
<a href="" id="comment"> ?</a>
```

With a static link to the next page, or dynamically set via JS based on your needs?

Here is a JSFiddle example using snippets of your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/chgeprsj/

Comment: Thank you, will try out your suggestion indeed

Comment: If it is dynamically set links you can do it via JS in the same place you set the inner text. Just bracket your IF statements and run the text and href setting in each appropriate block :)

Comment: Sorry, but I try to use your suggestion, but my BMI won't compute

Comment: @WanHazyan I added a JSFiddle to the answer, some adjustments for readability as I wrote it but it seems to work fine to me.

Comment: sorry. Working fine now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing these lines `document.getElementById("comment").innerText`

to `document.getElementById("comment").innerHtml` and then wrapping your suggestion text in an anchor tag `<a href=#>Underweight: Suggesting 7 days Weight Gain</a>`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much. This is very helpful indeed!